# Starting a simple data entry program. A method for writing values in variables from an entry text ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to write a simple program to collect data from pieces of texts by creating regular expressions to identify values through the phrases of the texts.

I want to start from something simple:

**The car is red**

I´m looking for a expression that let me to store the value red, or other possibles values such as blue, yellow, green if phrase changes. I want to do that from the interpreter or from a .txt file.

So my questions has two parts. One is to specify the value I want save. In this case "red", So I imagine a piece of code like {"The car is 'value'"} => value @color...Whatever be the regular expression that capture the syntax pattern of the language, Sorry I am not yet very familiar with the syntax of ruby , that's about precisely my question.
And the other part is about creating a variable to store the string "red" or whatever would be the case: yellow, green, brown...

I hope the question be clear.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve]". We expect to see evidence of your effort, along with a clear description of the problem you encountered. Without that it looks like you want us to write a tutorial or the code for you, both of which are off-topic. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" also helps explain our expectations. Currently it looks like you're asking before trying sufficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple using a match group:

```
string = "The car is red. The car is blue"
regex = /The car is (\w+)/
matches = string.scan(regex)
print matches
# => [["red"], ["blue"]]
print matches.flatten(1)
# => ["red", "blue"]
```

`(\w+)` in the regex is the match group. The parenthesis are the start and end bounds of the match. The match is what will be returned by `scan`. You can use multiple match groups if you want.

`\w` in regex is a non-word-boundary character. `\w+` effectively captures one word.

[cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Step-Definitions) makes use of this approach

Comment: I´d writed (The car is (\w+)) on rugular.com and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a regular expression that will extract desired word from the input. You can read about it in the official documentation about [Regexp class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html). You can also use [rubular.com](http://rubular.com) to test and play with expressions on sample data. You can assign match result to a variable in Ruby in the following way:

```
match = "The car is red".match(/red/)
color = match[0] unless match.nil?
```

or in a single line:

```
color, *_ = "The car is red".match(/red/).to_a
# color => "red"

color, *_ = "The car is red".match(/blue/).to_a
# color => nil
```

`match` method can extract multiple variables at once. In the sample code above, we've used only one (`color`). The method returns `MatchData` object as the result. Calling `to_a` will convert it to the array (note that empty match will produce an empty array so it is safe in this case). At the end you can assign it to a variable and forget the rest of results (they will be single variable in array anyway).

I didn't provide you a regexp, because this is a topic that you can learn your self depending on the use case (for your simple example, there is an example in the another answer).